# divide layered object into sections in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I wasn't sure how to title this but I have created a pizza in illustrator and I want to take a slice from the image and pull it out slightly. You can see in the image below the drawing I did in photoshop (right hand side image). I am trying to achieve the same thing in illustrator.

I have experimented with Pathfinder and clipping masks but can't quite seem to find the solution.

Any advice would much appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long time coming, but if you still need an answer, here is an option.

As long as all the objects on the pizza are vectors or paths, you can use the knife tool. Very easy to do. Harder to make a straight line with, but if you place guides in the angles you want for your slice, then you can drag the knife tool along the guides and it will divide the pizza.

Once the slice is made, just group the objects together and you can move the slice away from the rest of the pizza.

Comment: Hi KGehman, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!